# Installation issue in tanstack react query dev tools

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, react-query

I am using @tanstack/react-query and I have installed the dev tools. After the installation when tried to start the server I get this error. What should be done ?

./node_modules/@tanstack/match-sorter-utils/build/umd/index.production.js 504:47
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (504:47)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |     return e.rank === n.rank ? 0 : e.rank > n.rank ? -1 : 1;
  |   }, e.rankItem = function (e, n, t) {

> ```
> if ((t = t || {}).threshold = t.threshold ?? o.MATCHES, !t.accessors) {
> ```

|       const r = s(e, n, t);
|       return {

Comment: https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/4396